# Java - how to remove duplicates from a collection of timestamps?

Tags: java, collections, java-7

I have a List of timestamps in milliseconds and I want to compare them and remove duplicates not considering the milliseconds part. And process each unique value.

For example, `millis2` and `millis3` are different values if compared without truncating the milliseconds part (`2:28:14.100` vs `2:28:14.200`). But I need to disregard the millis and if the two values are compared truncated to seconds, they will be considered duplicates.

So I decided to create a List of timestamps, sort it in reverse order. Then iterate over the collection checking if truncated values are not equal. And add unique values to a `List<Long> deduped`.

```
    Long millis0 = 1554052261000L; // Sunday, March 31, 2019 5:11:01 PM
    Long millis1 = 1557023292000L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:12 AM
    Long millis2 = 1557023294100L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.100 AM
    Long millis3 = 1557023294200L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.200 AM

    List<Long> initialTimestamps = Arrays.asList(millis2, millis3, millis0, millis1);

    Comparator<Long> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(initialTimestamps, comparator);

    Long prevTs = null;
    List<Long> deduped = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Long ts: initialTimestamps) {
        if (prevTs != null && !millisToSeconds(prevTs).equals(millisToSeconds(ts))) {
        deduped.add(prevTs);
        process(prevTs)
    }
    prevTs = ts;
    deduped.add(prevTs);
    process(prevTs)
}
```

However when printing out the contents of `deduped`, there are duplicates:

```
Deduped timestamps ->
1557023294200
1557023294100
1557023294100
1557023292000
1557023292000
1554052261000
```

But I expect that after deduplication there will remain only `1557023294`, `1557023292` and `1554052261`.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You are calling deduped.add(prevTs) outside of the if-condition, i.e., whether or not this is a new value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use java 8, then you can use `stream().distinct()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Long millis0 = 1554052261000L; // Sunday, March 31, 2019 5:11:01 PM
    Long millis1 = 1557023292000L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:12 AM
    Long millis2 = 1557023294100L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.100 AM
    Long millis3 = 1557023294200L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.200 AM

    List<Long> initialTimestamps = Arrays.asList(millis2, millis3, millis0, millis1);
    List<Long> unique = initialTimestamps.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(unique);
}
```

For java < 8, you can put them in a `Set`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Long millis0 = 100L; // Sunday, March 31, 2019 5:11:01 PM
    Long millis1 = 100L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:12 AM
    Long millis2 = 200L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.100 AM
    Long millis3 = 200L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.200 AM

    List<Long> initialTimestamps = Arrays.asList(millis2, millis3, millis0, millis1);
    Set<Long> unique = new HashSet<Long>(initialTimestamps);

    System.out.println(unique);
}
```

## Update

As per your requirement to ignore the milliseconds, you can use a `Map` (if you want to preserve the millis) or use one of the approaches above, if you do not care about the milliseconds. In that case just divide the values by 1_000

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Long millis0 = 1554052261000L; // Sunday, March 31, 2019 5:11:01 PM
    Long millis1 = 1557023292000L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:12 AM
    Long millis2 = 1557023294100L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.100 AM
    Long millis3 = 1557023294200L; // Sunday, May 5, 2019 2:28:14.200 AM

    List<Long> initialTimestamps = Arrays.asList(millis2, millis3, millis0, millis1);
    Map<Long, Long> unique = new HashMap<>();

    for (Long timestamp : initialTimestamps) {
        unique.put(timestamp / 1000, timestamp);
    }

    System.out.println(unique.values());
}
```

If you want to preserve the first value of each duplicate, then use

```
if (!unique.containsKey(timestamp / 1000)) {
    unique.put(timestamp / 1000, timestamp);
}
```

instead of just `put()`. If you want to preserve the initial order of all timestamps, the you should use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`

Comment: Unfortunately I can use only Java 7

Comment: @Deadpool yeah, he updated teh question after I gave my answer. I've updated mine as well

Comment: Thanks. The only thing is that the order matters and when filtering out (1557023294200 vs 1557023294100) I have to leave 1557023294200 instead of 1557023294100

Comment: @samba You mean you always want the first value ?

Comment: Yes, that's why my initial idea was to first sort the timestamps in reverseOrder